# How to use INNER JOIN and UNION with a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, inner-join, union

I'm trying to find ingredients that are used in both *Spicy* and *Vegetarian* dishes. This exercise requires me to use **subqueries**, **inner join**, and **union**.

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT Ingredients.Name
FROM
(
  SELECT Tags.Name
  FROM Tags
  INNER JOIN DishesTags ON DishesTags.TagID = Tags.ID
  INNER JOIN Dishes ON DishesTags.DishID = Dishes.ID
  INNER JOIN DishesIngredients ON DishesIngredients.DishID = Dishes.ID
) Ingredients
WHERE Tags.Name IN ('Spicy', 'Vegetarian')
```

However, I do not quite understand how I could use union on joined subqueries?

[image: Here is the diagram of the database for reference]

Comment: Why do you *have* to use a `UNION`? Wouldn't an `EXISTS` be a better solution. `UNION` from your description, seems like the wrong choice to start with. Sample data and expected results might help us help you.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: What is your question? "use" for what? PS t where c or d is t where c union t where d. We can expect this is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses aggregation and a `having` clause for filtering:

```
select i.name
from ingredients i
inner join dishesingredients di on di.ingredientid = i.id
inner join dishestags dt on dt.dishid = di.dishid
inner join tags t on t.id = dt.tagid
where t.name in ('Spicy', 'Vegetarian')   -- either one tag or the other
group by i.id, i.name
having count(distinct t.name) = 2         -- both tags where found
```